# Are there any antisemitic caricatures from France during the interwar period?

Tags: france, art, antisemitism, interwar

I am looking for antisemitic caricatures in France between the two World Wars.
I can find examples both from before and after, e.g. ones related to the [Dreyfus case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreyfus_affair), but none during this period.

Are there no known example of historically significant antisemitic caricatures in France during this period?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a request for references/sources.

Comment: @TylerDurden, I'm really surprised to see that reference request is off topic on this stackexchange but as a non active member here I cannot complain ;-) I will edit the question in a minute in order that it fits with the standards accepted.

Comment: @GillesBonnet fwiw, that rule is normally only supposed to be applied to questions like "what's a good book for WW2".

Comment: @Semaphore Source requests for videos, pictures, cartoons, finger painting or whatever the heck it is are just as much off topic as asking for books. See this question: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14866/where-to-find-the-videos-of-the-nuremburg-trials

Comment: @TylerDurden With the caveat that community consensus is to allow requests for primary sources, see: [meta](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/897/4935).

Comment: It's a dumb rule. Good question.

Comment: @Semaphore It doesn't matter what the majority "consensus" is (a very VAGUE thing). What matters is that it takes FIVE votes to close a question, so that means that about 95%+ of the members have to consider your post on-topic, not 50%. There are very good reasons why source requests are OT, and trying to split hairs and say this source request is OT and this other one is not simply opens a can of worms where posters have no idea whether a post is OT or not. Making one-off exceptions creates confusion. What is needed is CLEAR standards so posters know what is OT and what is not.

Comment: The precedent on the site is to close questions that ask for pictures (see http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12157/where-can-i-find-historical-candidate-photos-of-u-s-elections-both-winners-and/12158). That precedent is clear and we should not create confusion by saying some questions asking for pictures are ok and others are not.

Comment: Agreed. Let's chuck out the whole silly rule.

Comment: The site works on consensus, not precedents. And the consensus is not to close such questions.

Comment: too many pedants coaming through questions looking for any reason to shut them down. Not a very good way to generate debate

Comment: Almost all Western countries had fascist/anti-Semitic movements in the 1930s, including both Britain and the United States. 

[This site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_far-right_movements_in_France#Between_the_wars)
 may tell you a little about what was going on in France.

Comment: @brianwatters SE sites explicitly do not want to generate debates.

Comment: OP is asking for primary sources, which is (imho), in scope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image: The sketch]

There are many examples of antisemitic caricatures in the far-right French press between the two world wars, especially in the thirties. 
It is not so easy to find them on the net (I don't know where to look), but a good library with a collection of the journal "Je suis partout", one of the most famous of those journals, should give you plenty of examples.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no reason for AntiSemitism in France to have died out because of the treaty of Versailles only to spring right back at the outbreak of WWII, the reasonable conclusion is that there were AntiSemitic cartoons as usual during the period, to reflect the known levels of AntiSemitism in France at the time.

Not to single out France, as there was an amount of this feeling in all countries in this period.